# How to Make my databse centre for more desktop apps

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection

I have developed a desktop app for my office. My company head office is in Mumbai. And now my boss wants to install that application at other branches like Delhi, Chennai etc. And we want to access the same database at all the branches. And we don't want to host the database at a server.

My office has LAN. So is it possible to make my database common for all the branch through my ip address of pc?

I have told my boss that we should host the DB at a server. Then the DB will be common for all the office. But my boss is telling me to make it without hosting if that is possible. If any body have any idea then reply me please..

Thanks...

Comment: Well, exposing a "naked" DB port to the Internet is not recommended. But, you could make a Virtual Private Network so all the remote offices are essentially on the same "logical LAN" even though they are physically far away.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at SymmetricDS, which is an open source (java) database syncing tool.

It operates over HTTP(S), and does multi-master replication.

So, you could have Java desktop at each site and have all the database sync.